# How should we type a callable with additional properties?

Tags: python, python-typing

As a toy example, let's use the Fibonacci sequence:

```py
def fib(n: int) -> int:
  if n < 2:
    return 1
  return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
```

Of course, this will hang the computer if we try to:

```py
print(fib(100))
```

So we decide to add memoization. To keep the logic of `fib` clear, we decide not to change `fib` and instead add memoization via a decorator:

```py
from typing import Callable
from functools import wraps


def remember(f: Callable[[int], int]) -> Callable[[int], int]:
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(n: int) -> int:
        if n not in wrapper.memory:
            wrapper.memory[n] = f(n)
        return wrapper.memory[n]

    wrapper.memory = dict[int, int]()
    return wrapper


@remember
def fib(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
```

Now there is no problem if we:

```
print(fib(100))
```

```
573147844013817084101
```

However, `mypy` complains that `"Callable[[int], int]" has no attribute "memory"`, which makes sense, and usually I would want this complaint if I tried to access a property that is not part of the declared type...

So, how should we use `typing` to indicate that `wrapper`, while a `Callable`, also has the property `memory`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think `Union` is applicable — `mypy` would then expect the object to be either of the one type or the other, and the object here *will* be a `Callable`. But if I have misunderstood you, post the code in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I meant _intersection_, sorry, but Python [doesn't have that](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/18).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To describe something as *"a callable with a memory attribute"*, you could define a [*protocol*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) (Python 3.8+, or earlier versions with [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/)):

```py
from typing import Protocol


class Wrapper(Protocol):
    memory: dict[int, int]
    def __call__(self, n: int) -> int: ...
```

In use, the type checker knows that a `Wrapper` is valid as a `Callable[[int], int]` and allows `return wrapper` as well as the assignment to `wrapper.memory`:

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable, cast


def remember(f: Callable[[int], int]) -> Callable[[int], int]:
    @wraps(f)
    def _wrapper(n: int) -> int:
        if n not in wrapper.memory:
            wrapper.memory[n] = f(n)
        return wrapper.memory[n]
    wrapper = cast(Wrapper, _wrapper)
    wrapper.memory = dict()
    return wrapper
```

[Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=1a5f8246e1eb1e7dd523ac04b4e5c8e0)

Unfortunately this requires `wrapper = cast(Wrapper, _wrapper)`, which is **not** type safe - `wrapper = cast(Wrapper, "foo")` would also check just fine.

Comment: That works — thanks! Actually, your answer helped me see a way to avoid the cast; see the edit I made to my original post. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @RichardAmbler please don't put answers in the question - revert the edit and post it _as an answer_.

Comment: This is not sufficient: `Wrapper` is missing the usual callable attributes like `__name__` or `__doc__`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a function attribute to store the cache, and you won't have this problem. You are already defining a closure (`wrapper` keeps a reference to the original callable), so store the cache in the closure as well.

```
from typing import Callable
from functools import wraps


def remember(f: Callable[[int], int]) -> Callable[[int], int]:
    cache: dict[int, int] = {}

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(n: int) -> int:
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = f(n)
        return cache[n]

    return wrapper


@remember
def fib(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of jonrsharpe's answer (which works, suggests the following, and I've accepted), we can avoid the need for a non type safe cast as follows:

```py
from typing import Callable
from functools import wraps


class Remember:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.memory = dict[int, int]()

    def __call__(self, f: Callable[[int], int]) -> Callable[[int], int]:
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(n: int) -> int:
            if n not in self.memory:
                self.memory[n] = f(n)
            return self.memory[n]

        return wrapper


@Remember()
def fib(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)


print(fib(100))
```

Comment: You could also write it to be used as `@Remember`, where `__init__` takes `f` and `__call__` _is_ the `wrapper`.